# How to reverse a list using an iterator in c++

Tags: c++, stl

I want to reverse the list a={1,2,3,4,5} using an iterator.According to my knowledge i know an iterator is a pointer that points to an element in the list.
So there are two questions which are as follows:

- Why does this code fail even though I am pointing to the last element in the    list and then decrementing the pointer to the previous address?

  ```
  list<int>::iterator i;
  for(i=l.end();i!=l.begin();i--)
     cout<<(*i);
  ```
- Second question is how do you access the third element in the list using an iterator without a for loop.Is it possible to access it without using a for loop?Please state the syntax if it is possible.

Comment: `end()` does not point to the last element in the list, it points *past* the last element. You have to *decrement* `end()` to reach the last element.

Comment: Look up `rbegin` and `rend`. Also look up `advance`.

Answer (score 5):

`l.end()` points after the last element, so in principle you need:

```
for(i=l.end()-1; i!=l.begin(); i--)              // invalid
```

but then you'll not get the first element (`l.begin()`) as you stop when you reach it.

Further it is not valid to subtract 1 from a list iterator so it must be:

```
for(i=std::prev(l.end()); i!=l.begin(); i--)     // valid
```

But still you have the problem with the first element.

**A better way is to use reverse iterator**. Something like:

```
for (std::list<int>::reverse_iterator i = l.rbegin(); i != l.rend(); ++i)
```

For your second question you could do:

```
auto it = l.begin();
cout << *(std::next(it, 2));
```

Here is a list of valid operations depending on iterator type: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/

And here you can see that list has a bidirectional iterator: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: Your first example won't compile because `std::list::end` is a _bidirectional iterator_ so you can't subtract an integer from `l.end()`

Comment: There is an error in your *(l.begin()+2) it is throwing an error 'no match for operator +'.And i think the same error will apply when you assign i=l.end()-1

Comment: @navroze: That's because you can't just add or subtract a number from `std::list` iterators. Bidirectional iterators don't support that operation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace so how can I access the elements using an iterator

Comment: @navroze: If you look at the last example in this question `std::next(it, 2)` is one way to get an iterator two places past `it`. It's easier with something like a `std::vector` iterator because then you could do `it + 2`. If you want to iterate the whole container in reverse, use _reverse iterators_ like the examples in all of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also By [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/rbegin/):

```
for (std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rit=mylist.rbegin(); rit!=mylist.rend(); ++rit)
    std::cout << ' ' << *rit;
```

You can do it By [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) in C++.

```
int temp[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

std::vector<int>v(temp, temp+3);

std::vector<int> n_v(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

Comment: If i do it with vectors i can access the element directly but in case of list i cannot do it hence i needed a solution in list.Any way thanks for putting it up

Comment: I give you two option. **List & vector**. So it's your choice

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse_iterator to travel a container in reverse.

```
list<int>::reverse_iterator i;
for(i=l.rbegin();i!=l.rend();i++)
    cout<<(*i);
```

As for acessing the 3rd element of the list you have to iterate to it. There is no direct access to elements in a list

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to reverse a list in place, you can use this `std::reverse`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> values { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::reverse(values.begin(), values.end());
    for (int i : values)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Comment: There's actually a [`std::list::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/reverse) member function that I'd use as a first choice. It may be more efficient because it has access to the container implementation details.

Comment: If there exists such function, I would believe that `std::reverse` has overloaded implementation which just call `std::list::reverse` and that one function to call is merely no performance slow down.